# SQL commands to check ID difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

How do I know IDs that are in one table and not on the other table? How would I accomplish that?

And then I want to delete all such IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
delete from t1
using table1 as t1
left outer join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

It's worth noting that joins are faster than subqueries.

Comment: Agreed, your solution is better.  If table2 has a large number of rows, doing a NOT IN (subquery) would be a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, although I remembered a quirk of MySQL (aren't there plenty?) wherein you can't left outer join in a delete without a `using` clause, so it looks a little gross.  Still, better than a dependent subquery.

Comment: Why are joins faster than subqueries?

Comment: MySQL does not optimize subqueries very well.  Check out this article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/

Comment: I got #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction either way. Only 12k rows.

Comment: There can be a number of things contributing to that, unfortunately.  I don't think it's a question of the join/subquery question.  I recommend breaking the delete into a series of ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Use this query:

```
 delete from TABLE_A where ID not in (select ID from TABLE_B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
delete from t1 
where id not in
(select t2.id from t2)
```